# How can I get my view to display the property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using the Prism Library I've successfully been able to create a working ViewModel. However when I try to set any property it won't display in the view.

In this example the method OnSumbit sets the Name to "Hello", but this doesn't display it in the View. How can I get it to be displayed in the View?

```
class ItemTemplateVM : BindableBase
{
    private ItemTemplateModel itemTemplateModel;

    public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; private set; }

    public ItemTemplateVM()
    {
        this.SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnSubmit);
        this.ItemTemplateModel = new ItemTemplateModel();
    }

    private void OnSubmit()
    {
        this.ItemTemplateModel.Name = "Hello";
    }

    public ItemTemplateModel ItemTemplateModel
    {
        get { return this.itemTemplateModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this.itemTemplateModel, value); }
    }
```

XAML

```
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ItemTemplateModel.Entry, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ItemTemplateModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ItemTemplateModel.Displayid, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"/>
```

Comment: have you set the DataContext for the view?

Comment: Yes. Everything is working as it should, just not when I set a property like this. I will add that if I set the property in the constructor it will display in the view, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Since you have named it `ItemTemplate`, is it correct that this is applied to elements in a List / ItemsControl? If so, how do you bind that lists ItemsSource?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: no worries :) If you debug your program, do you enter the `OnSubmit` method? Do you see any errors in the debug output?

Comment: No errors show. I did some testing and set the property then checked if that property was indeed changed and it was. It just won't display that change in the view.

Comment: does `ItemTemplateModel` also derive from `BindableBase` or some other way fire `PropertyChanged` events?

Comment: No ItemTemplateModel does not inherit anything. Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, because you bind directly to that class properties. There are two solutions where that solution is the easiest one. I'll write up an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three bindings in your xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemTemplateModel.Entry, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemTemplateModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemTemplateModel.Displayid, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and they all three bind directly to the object `ItemTemplateModel`s properties. Since that class do not fire `PropertyChanged` the view is never notified about the changes, so, the easiest solution here is to make `ItemTemplateModel` inherit from `BindableBase` and then change the Properties so that they look similar to the viewmodels, i.e.

```
...
set { SetProperty(ref this.Entry, value); }
...
```

On the other hand, it is better (IMO) to expose those properties directly from the viewmodel, and use the Model solely as a data object, so for me, the better solution would be something like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Entry, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Displayid, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

.

```
class ItemTemplateVM : BindableBase
{
    private ItemTemplateModel itemTemplateModel;

    ...
    public ItemTemplateModel ItemTemplateModel
    {
        get { return this.itemTemplateModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this.itemTemplateModel, value); }
    }

    public string Entry {
        get { return itemTemplateModel.Entry; }
        set {
            if (itemTemplateModel.Entry == value)
                return;

            itemTemplateModel.Entry = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(); // I believe this is the prism variant of firing PropertyChanged
        }
    }

    // same for Name and DisplayId
```

Also, do note that there is a concept in WPF named [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so the name `ItemTemplateViewModel` for a general ViewModel is an unfortunate name. I believe it would be better to name it < ViewName>ViewModel, i.e. if your view is named `MyView`, call the viewmodel `MyViewModel`

Comment: Thank you for the two possible solutions! Just one more question, is the way I use the model breaking the MVVM pattern?

Comment: No, I do not think so. There can be some extra tinkering if you need to serialize the model somehow (save state or similar) and the model has a lot of logic. For that reason, try to keep the model as clean as possible and all of the logic in the viewmodel. Using NotifyPropertyChanged (for instance via BindableBase) in your model should not cause any issues.